# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - Release Management with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to use Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - Release Management feature in Jenkins pipeline but I don't see any pipeline step in document (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax).

I'm looking for pipeline step either in scripted/declarative step for "Staging a Maven Release Build". PFA the screenshot which can be done by normal maven job.

Does anyone has workaround for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRp0V.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You didn't ask any question here. Please note that the more focussed your post is on a single problem, the more likely it is that someone can help you. We are not a normal forum here, please read our [help page on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first! Then [edit] your question, possibly with a small example and a focussed question.

Comment: I am also very interested to have this feature in declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

while this feature does not yet exist in the Declarative pipeline, it does in the Scripted one.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenReleaseManagementwithArtifactory) and/or open a feature request for this to be supported in the Declarative pipeline on [JFrogs' public Jira](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/) (under the HAP project).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response but i did go through the declarative pipeline steps i don't seem to see for staging maven build - either declarative/scripted.(Sorry, i should have been more specific in my question)